# Assist with MySQL Debug of duplicated results in Magento Database

Tags: magento-1.7, database

Hopefully, someone can highlight the errors of my ways with this problem that I have created for myself. Your help is appreciated.

**Brief**

Gather all orders made within a specific period and list all product SKUs in the order as a concatenated row.

**Problem**

The results in the SKU field are being duplicated

**Query**

```
SELECT
    increment_id AS 'Order Number',
    orders.created_at AS 'Ordered On',
    customer_email AS 'Email',
    address.firstname AS 'First Name',
    address.lastname AS 'Surname',
    GROUP_CONCAT(items.sku SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'SKUs'
FROM
    sales_flat_order AS orders 
    JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id
WHERE
    orders.created_at BETWEEN  '2016-01-1 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    increment_id
```

**Output Example**

```
Order Number    First Name  Surname Email       SKUs
0000001         John        Doe     d1@ex.com   123456, 123456
0000002         Jane        Doe     d2@ex.com   789456, 789456
0000003         Bob         Smith   s3@ex.com   456123, 123456, 456123, 123456
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(items.sku) SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Comment: Tried and tested - This does the job. Thank you, Konstantin.

Comment: you are very welcome Graig